# Change a cell's color on value of another cell, then change to a different color if I put a value into the cell

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I was wondering if anyone could help me with a situation I have come across.  I want Cell C1 to turn yellow whenever A1="Bananas".  But I also want cell C1 to turn to white whenever I put any form of text into the cell.  Is there a way to satisfy both requirements?

Comment: use `=AND(A1="Bananas",C1="")` for yellow conditional formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with [conditional formatting](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/quick-start-apply-conditional-formatting-HA010370614.aspx).

You're going to need 2 rules for cell C1:

1. Formula: `=$C$1<>""` ; Format: No formatting ; **stop if true**
2. Formula: `=$A$1="Bananas"` ; Format: Yellow fill

**OR (using @simico's suggestion from the comments below):**

1 Conditional formatting rule:

1. Formula: `=AND(A1="Bananas",$C$1="")` ; Format: Yellow fill

That should do it.

Comment: why not single CF for yellow: `=AND(A1="Bananas",C1="")`?

Comment: Thanks, @simoco! Equally as good - Probably better on the calculation engine.

Comment: I wasn't able to get either one of those to work, but I was able to tinker enough to get what I needed accomplished.  The other wrinkle that I have is this: How do I get C1 to change a different color if B1 contains a name from an list that is in D1:D10.  So if A1="Bananas", I need C1 to turn yellow.  If A1="Bananas" and C1 has text in it, C1 needs to go back to white.  If A1="Bananas",B1=a name from a list in D1:D10, and C1 has text in it, then C1 will turn blue.

Comment: I don't know how things went wrong with not being able to get the steps above to work, so I can't offer a more accurate solution, but, since you're now starting to want such an array of custom criteria, I would definitely suggest using the multiple rules approach so you can do / test each condition separately and control the hierarchy, but for B1 needing to have a value in a list, you can accomplish this using something along the lines of `=ISNUMBER(MATCH($B$1,$D$1:$D$10,0))` for your conditional format condition